# Sports R Function issues; else-if?

Tags: r, if-statement

Based on the following `k1`, `k2`, `k3` and `x` values

```
x = GP$PDiff

k1 = 35*sin(0.0561*x)

k2 = -(1/7)*x + 39

k3 = 30
```

I have the following `if...else` issue

```
if (x <= 28){{

  elo <- eloRating(home="HomeTeam", away="AwayTeam", homeScore="HomeScore", awayScore = "AwayScore",
                   data = GP, kfactor = k1, initialRating = 1500, homeAdvantage = 0)
}

  else if (x > 28|x <= 35){

    elo <- eloRating(home="HomeTeam", away="AwayTeam", homeScore="HomeScore", awayScore = "AwayScore",
                     data = GP, kfactor = k2, initialRating = 1500, homeAdvantage = 0)
  }

  else{
    elo <- eloRating(home="HomeTeam", away="AwayTeam", homeScore="HomeScore", awayScore = "AwayScore",
                     data = GP, kfactor = k3, initialRating = 1500, homeAdvantage = 0) 
  }
}
```

When I try to run it, I get errors saying "unexpected 'else' in '     else'" and there are also errors with my bracket.

I have tried running it with `elseif`, I have tried following several other suggested questions, but have not been able to figure it out.

I'm running it with a changing `x` value and have been suggested to try a `for` loop, but I'm a relative noob in R and don't know how to set up a `for` loop in this situation.

Comment: I think you have an extra set of brackets around the first `if`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding an else case at the end, and then making a separate condition for the x>28 | x<=35.

There's probably a more elegant way to do this, but this way does work.

```
if (x <= 28){

  elo <- eloRating(home="HomeTeam", away="AwayTeam", homeScore="HomeScore", awayScore = "AwayScore",
                   data = GP, kfactor = k1, initialRating = 1500, homeAdvantage = 0)
}

  else{
      if (x > 28|x <= 35){

      elo <- eloRating(home="HomeTeam", away="AwayTeam", homeScore="HomeScore", awayScore = "AwayScore",
                     data = GP, kfactor = k2, initialRating = 1500, homeAdvantage = 0)
  }

  else{
    elo <- eloRating(home="HomeTeam", away="AwayTeam", homeScore="HomeScore", awayScore = "AwayScore",
                     data = GP, kfactor = k3, initialRating = 1500, homeAdvantage = 0) 
  }}
```